# How to get PayPal commerce platform live credentials?

Tags: paypal, marketplace, paypal-marketplaces

Our company is trying to setup a PayPal commerce platform, however we are not able to understand the steps needed to get access in the live environment. We have access through our sandbox account. The company is based in Italy, however on there site nothing is stated that this would be an issue.

What are the steps to get live credentials?
How long does approval need?

BTW we already filled all kinds of forms for this and it seems to be impossible to get in touch with the support.

Answer (score 1):

Forms are the correct thing to be filling out, it seems you've already found this page: https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces

Which has a link to the global partner program, which as a link to the following for Italy: https://www.paypal.com/it/webapps/mpp/partner-programme-login

Assuming you've already filled this out, that's it. As I understand it there is plenty of interest in using such APIs, and only certain companies are contacted back to arrange approval.

Comment: thanks for you reply. Yes we tried all of them, why would paypal attract companies with this Marketplace if they are not going to onboard them?